# Memory Leak in a Simple Metal Program

Tags: objective-c++, metal

I am trying to learn Metal for scientific programming. I tried creating a simple kernel that did morphological dilation. The issue that I am facing is that the memory seems to be increasing by a couple of KBs every time I call `dilate` on an image.

I verified the memory leak by running the `dilate` method in a for loop for 10000 iterations, and watched the allocated memory in Xcode's debug navigator grow from 16MB to 17 MBs.

Is there anything that you see in my code that would contribute to the memory leak? I have also pushed the project to [Github](https://github.com/siavashk/metallurgy) in case that helps.

```
class MorphologyIOS : public Morphology
{
public:
    MorphologyIOS(
        const uint kernel,
        const uint width,
        const uint height
    ) {
        device_ = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
        kernelSize_ = kernel;
        buffer_ = [device_ newBufferWithBytes:&kernelSize_ length:4 options:MTLStorageModeShared];
        library_ = [device_ newDefaultLibrary];
        commandQueue_ = [device_ newCommandQueue];
        identityFunction_ = [library_ newFunctionWithName:@"identity"];

        MTLTextureDescriptor* readDesc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormat::MTLPixelFormatR8Uint
            width:width height:height mipmapped:false];

        MTLTextureDescriptor* writeDesc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormat::MTLPixelFormatR8Uint
            width:width height:height mipmapped:false];

        [writeDesc setUsage:MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite];

        inTexture_ = [device_ newTextureWithDescriptor:readDesc];
        outTexture_ = [device_ newTextureWithDescriptor:writeDesc];

        entireImage_ = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height);

        pipelineState_ = [device_ newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:identityFunction_ error:NULL];

    }

    virtual ~MorphologyIOS() override {}

    virtual std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> dilate(
        const std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>& inImage
    ) override {
        void* result = malloc(outTexture_.width * outTexture_.height);
        std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> outImage;
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            commandBuffer_ = [commandQueue_ commandBuffer];
            commandEncoder_ = [commandBuffer_ computeCommandEncoder];
            [commandEncoder_ setComputePipelineState:pipelineState_];

            [inTexture_ replaceRegion:entireImage_ mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:inImage.get() bytesPerRow:outTexture_.width];

            [commandEncoder_ setTexture:inTexture_ atIndex:0];
            [commandEncoder_ setTexture:outTexture_ atIndex:1];
            [commandEncoder_ setBuffer:buffer_ offset:0 atIndex:0];

            MTLSize threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(10, 10, 1);
            MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(inTexture_.width / threadGroupCount.width,
                inTexture_.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1);

            [commandEncoder_ dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCount];
            [commandEncoder_ endEncoding];
            [commandBuffer_ commit];
            [commandBuffer_ waitUntilCompleted];

            [outTexture_ getBytes:result bytesPerRow:outTexture_.width fromRegion:entireImage_ mipmapLevel:0];
            outImage.reset(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(result));
        }

        return outImage;
    }
private:
    id<MTLDevice> device_;
    uint kernelSize_;
    id<MTLBuffer> buffer_;
    id<MTLLibrary> library_;
    id<MTLComputePipelineState> pipelineState_;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue_;
    id<MTLFunction> identityFunction_;
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer_;
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> commandEncoder_;
    id<MTLTexture> inTexture_;
    id<MTLTexture> outTexture_;
    MTLRegion entireImage_;
};
```

And my kernel looks like this:

```
kernel void dilation(
    texture2d<uint, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
    texture2d<uint, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
    device uint *kernelSize [[buffer(0)]],
    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]
) {
    uint halfKernel = kernelSize[0] / 2;
    uint minX = gid.x >= halfKernel ? gid.x - halfKernel : 0;
    uint minY = gid.y >= halfKernel ? gid.y - halfKernel : 0;
    uint maxX = gid.x + halfKernel < inTexture.get_width() ? gid.x + halfKernel : inTexture.get_width();
    uint maxY = gid.y + halfKernel < inTexture.get_height() ? gid.y + halfKernel : inTexture.get_height();
    uint maxValue = 0;
    for (uint i = minX; i <= maxX; i++)
    {
        for (uint j = minY; j <= maxY; j++)
        {
            uint4 value = inTexture.read(uint2(i, j));
            if (maxValue < value[0])
                maxValue = value[0];
        }
    }
    outTexture.write(maxValue, gid);
}
```

Comment: `shared_ptr` uses `delete` by default, which does not work well with memory allocated with `malloc()` (as opposed to `new`).

Comment: Thank you @KenThomases. I replaced my `malloc`s with `new` throughout the code, such as `unsigned char* result = new unsigned char[outTexture_.width * outTexture_.height];`, but I still get the memory leak. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @KenThomases, I tried your suggestion with other data containers, such as `std::vector<unsigned char>` as well. The result was the same. I have a feeling that the issue is somewhere else. :(

Comment: Do you see the same growth in memory when you run without the Metal validation layer enabled? (You can configure your scheme's run options by pressing Cmd+Opt+R; try turning off both Frame Capture and Validation).

Comment: You can also run your app using the Allocations template in Instruments. That should show you exactly what's being allocated and not released.

Comment: @warrenm If I disable frame capture, then I do not see a leak. Is that just a Metal bug? What does that tell you? Thanks. :)

Comment: It's not so much a bug as it is an artifact of the capture/validation layer doing some bookkeeping on your behalf. Since it won't occur in real-world usage, it's probably not something to worry about.

Comment: Thanks @warrenm. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: By the way, I was expecting computation on the GPU to be blazingly faster than the CPU. 1000 dilations for a 1000 by 1000 image takes about 2 seconds on my MacBook Air. I am suspecting that my kernel/textures setup is not optimized. Could you point me in the right direction? Maybe recommend some resources? Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since I implemented dilation, and I've never done it on the GPU, but the first thing I'd look at is whether your dilation kernel is separable. Often it's possible to transform a one-pass O(n^2) solution (where n is the kernel radius) into a two-pass O(n) solution. The aggregate bandwidth savings in such a situation can be massive.

Comment: It seems that I have been reinventing the wheel. Apple has Metal Performance Shaders (MSP) and they have also implemented dilation. Still it is good to reimplement something for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much a bug as it is an artifact of the capture/validation layer doing some bookkeeping on your behalf. Since it won't occur in real-world usage, it's probably not something to worry about.